Shortcuts running privileged commands
Intro: Using ABIs to control fan_speed, fn_lock, or conservation mode can be done with editing files in the (e.g. /sys/bus/platform/.../) directory which is owned by root.
For example if i wanted to change my fan speed
i need to run this command echo 1 | sudo tee /path/to/fan_mode.
What I wanted: To make shortcuts so that I can control performance, fan speed, camera, fn lock on the fly, without a password.
The problem: If i used sudoers or doas.conf, files to make it run without password, it would compromise security (at least if i don't fully understand what I'm doing).
The question: What is the best way to do this kind of stuff without compromising security?
What i have tried:
Added this line to sudoers:
%wheel ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/fn_lock

and made a shortcut that runs sudo /usr/local/bin/fn_lock
and made a script (/usr/local/bin/fn_lock) that toggles the contents of the file, between 1 and 0.
Problems with that approach were: I

don't really know if this is secure.
In the script, I can't run commands as non-root user ( such as notification commands ).

